# How to Bind property to Value of Property in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a custom class called TextBoxColumn as Follows

```
public class TextBoxColumn : DataGridTemplateColumn
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FieldNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FieldName", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxColumn), new PropertyMetadata(""));
    public string FieldName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FieldNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FieldNameProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

When creating DataGrid columns from XAML:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <local:TextBoxControl FieldName="FirstName"/>
        <local:TextBoxControl FieldName="LastName"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In XAML Dictionary, I have defined the Cell Template for this TextBoxColumn:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TextBoxColumn_CellTemplate">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding FieldName}"/> <!-- Here is the problem, if I give FirstName instead of FieldName, it works fine -->
</DataTemplate>`
```

How to get the value of FieldName property of TextBoxColumn and Bind it to Text property? How can I achieve it without C# code?

Comment: Why not use a `DataGridTextColumn`?

Answer (score 1):

Give a name to TextBoxColumn control and try to bind it's property by element name

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=txtBoxCol, Path=FieldName}"></TextBox>
```

Comment: It is showing the value of the FieldName for that TextBoxControl e.g. FirstName, LastName etc, not binding with FirstName or LastName (the value of FieldName)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do thing without code, there is no way to bind properties of a binding (in this case you would want [`Binding.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) to be whatever the `FieldName` is).